# Georeferenced Image Rendering As Black Shape in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I'm georeferencing an image in QGIS, it shows up fine on the georeferencer and goes to about the right position on the map where it's supposed to. But as you can see below, the image shows up as a black box.

Any suggestions for a fix?

[image: In Georeferencer]
[image: After Georeferencing]

Comment: Is the source file RGB or paletted colors? Gimp or any other image sotfware can tell you that.

Comment: Gdalinfo can tell it as well.

Comment: I checked the information and its RGB in 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

I take it this is a screen grab from Google Earth? If I was georeferencing this I wouldn't use lat/lon, I'd use a projected coordinate system. You can set Google Earth to display UTM coordinates that you can use for your control points.

You'll probably find a two-point calibration will will be good enough (one point say bottom-left and the other say top-right). Set the georeferencer to use 'Helmert' and 'Linear.'

In QGIS, in your case, the CRS to select when georeferencing the image will be WGS84/UTM Zone 13N (EPSG:32613).

Comment: Would it make a difference if this was an aerial done by the county? I'll try your suggestion and see if anything changes.