# QGIS-LTR georeference error

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, point, coordinates, georeferencing

I am attempting to georeference an image in QGIS-LTR basically following the tutorial here (https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/georeferencing_basics.html). I put in six points and hit the green button and this pops out:

[image]

Any ideas of how to fix this?

For reference, here is what my point table looks like:

[image]

The six points are in the four corners and in the top middle and bottom middle when I am georeferencing, but then something goes awry.

Note that my error seems to be similar to the one here ([Georeferenced Image Rendering As Black Shape in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167667/georeferenced-image-rendering-as-black-shape-in-qgis)), but I am not sure if the solutions given were correct.

Comment: Did you use a reasonable target CRS and not some crazy target resolution?

Comment: I don’t know a lot about that. The lat/lons are from Google Earth. What is the best CRS to use?

Comment: That depends on your image. The best CRS would be the one that most closely resembles the one that your image originally was taken/drawn in.